# Multiple Plans with Stripe on Rails & No Customer Payment Source

Tags: stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-5

I have `Stripe` setup with `Rails` and `Devise`. It works beautifully, but there is three errors.

First of all, I would like to implement two different plans. Once they select it with the `Pay With Stripe` button, `Stripe` would do the work of making the customer pay the plan they choose monthly.

Second issue: When I go to the `/charges/new` path, it works beautifully and shows the plans. However, when I go to the `/charges` path, it gives me the error of `This customer has no attached payment source`.

Third issue: The user is suppose to go from `/users/new` to the `/charges/new`. This isn't happening.

How would I fix all of these errors?

Here's my `charges_controller.rb`:

```
 class ChargesController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!

      def new
      end

      def update
      end

      def create
           token = params[:stripeToken]

           customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
                source: token,
                plan: 2020,
                email: current_user.email,
            )

            current_user.subscribed = true
            current_user.stripeid = customer.id
            current_user.save

            redirect_to profile_path
      end
 end
```

Here's my `routes.rb` file:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}, path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout", registration: "signup", sign_up: "cmon_lemme_in_guys" }
      resources :things
      resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]

      get "charges", to: "charges#create"

      authenticated :user do
           root "things#profile"
           get "profile", to: "things#profile"
       end

      root "index#welcome"
      get "license/terms"
 end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can really help with 2/3, but with regards to question 1, you need to use the [Create a Plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan) API Endpoint to build the two plans, then [Create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) to build a customer record for each of your users.  Finally, you'd attach the Plan as a Subscription to the Customer using the [Create a Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) API Endpoint.

Comment: @korben - Thanks! That worked like a charm.